# Is there a cryptocurrency with transparent and clear ledger?

Tags: cryptocurrency

It seems that the current trend in the cryptocurrencies is to to strive for more anonymity and untraceability but since there is a danger governments to try to shut them down because of the money laundering and terrorism funding concerns I was wondering: Is there a cryptocurrency with transparent ledger, i.e. where all the transactions (from/to, amount) are stored in clear form?

Also, is there a cryptocurrencty which optionally supports functionality for all/some addresses to be registered with central (tax) authority?

Comment: It seems... hmmm? Bitcoin, for example, is designed to assert full traceability...

Comment: BitCoin, like most cryptocoins is pseudonymous, not (fully) anonymous. And it's indeed fully traceable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on bitcoin.SE

Comment: @RonJohn It is not belonging to bitcoin SE because it essentially asks for alternative to bitcoin...

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What would a "from/to" "in clear form" be exactly? Actual names? Account numbers? Or what? (Also, @Ognyan, it would be entirely appropriate on bitcoin.SE. Bitcoin.SE got its name when there pretty much only was bitcoin, but similar systems and system design absolutely are on topic there.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok, I will repost the question there. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real need for the "register" functionality; you can implement the same by having a public tax wallet to which new wallets must pay the smallest possible amount (i.e. 1 satoshi for bitcoin), attaching the user's ID in the metadata.

Of course, being a blockchain, this data is then public. You don't register with just the tax authorities, you register with the world. This probably explains why no tax authority has bothered to set this up. The average tax authority is happy enough if you just include your wallet ID in your tax statement.